# Adding values of radio buttons to array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to make student skip form and adding values to array, but there is "Undefined offset: 3" error.
Here is the controller:

```
    public function skip(Request $request, $data = array())
    {
        $students = Student::where('group_id', 1)->get();
        $result=[];

        if ($request->has('submit')) {
            foreach($students as $student) {
               array_push($result, $data[$student->id]);
            }}
        return view ('skip', compact('students', 'result'));
    }
}
```

And view:

```
                        <form method="POST" action="">
                            @csrf
                            @foreach($students as $student)

                                <div class="radiobtns-group">

                                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">

                                        {{$student->id}}

                                        <label class="btn btn-success">

                                            <input type="radio" name="{{$student->id}}" value="1" autocomplete="off" checked>Yes
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="btn btn-danger">

                                            <input type="radio" name="{{$student->id}}" value="0" autocomplete="off">No
                                        </label>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>




                    <button name='submit' type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Add
                    </button>

                    </form>
                    {{print_r($result)}}
```

I know, it needs to be done in JS, but I don't know it yet. Maybe you can help or guide in other ways to solve it.
Thank You!

Comment: Your `$data` variable does not have key 3, that's why it prints that error, you can print `$data` to understand what goes wrong.

Comment: can you tell me how i can do it, because when i'm clicking it returns only error and i can't see dd() or var_dump()

Comment: Can you show me the route? I don't know what is the propose of `$data` variable, could you explain me?

Comment: @MiqayelSrapionyan of course, 'Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/skip', [SkipController::class, 'skip']);' i just want to pass the button data and student_id to the database. But before that, I wanted to see how $ data takes values ​​- whether it immediately collects into an array or overwrites the values ​​in the foreach array and needs to collect them into an array

Comment: I just don't understand what you trying to achieve in the foreach loop?

Comment: please check my answer and comment, if something is wrong, i will help you, @ichwillkin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `$data`, you need to get it from `$request` object.

And you need to specify your radio inputs `name` and value correctly like this.
I will show how to achieve it below.

```
@foreach($students as $key => $student)
   <div class="radiobtns-group">
     <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        {{$student->id}}
        <label class="btn btn-success">
            <input type="radio" name="student-{{$key}}" value="1" 
             autocomplete="off" checked>Yes
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-danger">
          <input type="radio" name="student-{{$key}}" value="0" 
              autocomplete="off">No
        </label>
      </div>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

And now you can receive `student-$key`(it can be like `student-0, student-1` etc.) property in your `$request` option.
Now you can iterate throw your database students and do like below.

```
public function skip(Request $request)
{
        $students = Student::where('group_id', 1)->get();
        $result = [];

        if ($request->has('submit')) {
            foreach($students as $key => $student) {
               if(!$request->has("student-$key")) continue; // In case when none answered

               $result[$student->id] = $request->get("student-$key");
            }
        }

        return view ('skip', compact('students', 'result'));
}
```

So we have collected `$result` which `key` is student id and value is 1 or 0.

Comment: Glad to help you :)